# What table naming convention is best for ORM

Tags: linq, orm, schema, naming-conventions

I recently started work at a new shop that uses a table naming convention like the following:

- Users
- UserRoles
- UserUserRoles
- UserProfiles
- UserProfileLanguages

The convention I've been using is:

- Users
- Roles
- UserRoleMaps
- Profiles
- Languages

When my boss asked why I don't prefix my tables, I explained that a database diagram would explain all the relationships much better than any naming convention could. **I'm I wrong to assume that?**

I'm willing to admit that the first example is more complete (especially if you're only looking at the tables directly), **but what's the preferred solution for ORM?** For example, in LINQ I would access my user's language like so:

```
User.Profile.Language
```

whereas, the first example would be:

```
User.UserProfile.UserProfileLanguage
```

Sure, I could easily rename my tables in the LINQ designer to whatever I please, but that quickly becomes a hassle if the data schema keeps changing.

EDIT: Removed APP_ prefix in example because it's not relevant to this question.

Comment: Why prefix every table with the app name? What other prefixes are used besides that?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention... my shop uses a single database for all applications because "they often need to join data from different apps". That's another question entirely, but I just have to accept it for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I could easily rename my tables in the LINQ designer to whatever I please